# how to get top n values in pandas dataframe if it has repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a pandas dataframe say:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x |
| 1 | b | y |
| 1 | c | z |
| 2 | a | x |
| 2 | b | x |
| 3 | a | y |
| 4 | a | z |

If i wanted top 2 values by x, I mean top 2 values by x column which gives:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x |
| 1 | b | y |
| 1 | c | z |
| 2 | a | x |
| 2 | b | x |

If i wanted top 2 values by y, I mean top 2 values by y column which gives:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x |
| 1 | b | y |
| 2 | a | x |
| 2 | b | x |
| 3 | a | y |
| 4 | a | z |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `df.groupby('desired_col').head(2)`

Comment: @mozway I don't think it's the right answer but maybe I'm wrong :-)

Comment: @Corralien maybe you're right, in any case OP should put more effort in describing the logic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> df[df['x'].isin(df['x'].value_counts().head(2).index)]
   x  y  z
0  1  a  x
1  1  b  y
2  1  c  z
3  2  a  x
4  2  b  x

>>> df[df['y'].isin(df['y'].value_counts().head(2).index)]
   x  y  z
0  1  a  x
1  1  b  y
3  2  a  x
4  2  b  x
5  3  a  y
6  4  a  z
```

Comment: hi, it works but it changes the order of the dataframe and doesn't give top 2 according to previous dataframe. How to maintain the same order and get top 2 values

Comment: My output and your expected result are the same. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
def select_top_k(df, col, top_k):
    grouping_df = df.groupby(col)
    gr_list = list(grouping_df.groups)[:top_k]
    
    temp = grouping_df.filter(lambda x: x[col].iloc[0] in gr_list)
    return temp
```

```
data = {'x': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
        'y': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'],
        'z': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

col = 'x'
top_k = 2

select_top_k(df, col, top_k)
```

Comment: Hi, it works but it shorts the dataframe i want top values in the same dataframe without sorting.